# Adding additional properties that can be inferred with a class that is using a generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am working on creating a simple ORM for a database that runs in memory for testing purposes.

It'd require you to define the models first, then the database would use those models.
the database would then have an additional property in the constructor to define the relations for those models.

what I am trying to do is to get the relational properties to be inferred. How could I do that?

```js
interface BaseModel {
  id: string
}

class Model<ModelProps extends BaseModel>{
  data: ModelProps[] = []
  constructor(object?: ModelProps) {
  }
}

class Database<
  T extends BaseModel,
  ModelsIndex extends { [key: string]: Model<T> },
  ModelsIndexKeys extends keyof ModelsIndex,
  Relations extends Partial<{ [key in ModelsIndexKeys]: any }>
  > {
  models: ModelsIndex
  constructor(models: ModelsIndex, relations?: Relations) {
    this.models = models
  }
}

interface IUserModel {
  id: string,
  name: string
}

interface IRoleModel {
  id: string,
  title: string
}

interface IPostModel {
  id: string,
  title: string,
  body: string,
}



const userModel = new Model<IUserModel>()
const roleModel = new Model<IRoleModel>()
const postModel = new Model<IPostModel>()

// adds more properties and functionalities to the model
const HasOne = (model: any) => {

}

// adds more properties and functionalities to the model
const HasMany = (model: any) => {

}

type role = "role"
type pluralRole = `${role}s`


const db = new Database(
  { user: userModel, role: roleModel, post: postModel },
  {
    user:
    {
      userRole: HasOne(roleModel),
      post: HasMany(postModel)
    }
  })

/**
 * Goal
 */

// since we defined "userRole" as the property name
// I'd want to have 'userRole' and 'userRoleId' as additional properties for the model that can be inferred

// expected infers:
// db.models.user.data[0].userRoleId
// db.models.user.data[0].userRole

// expected infers:
// db.models.user.data[0].posts    -- notice that we defined it as 'post', but it was changed to the plural 'posts' thorugh template literal types
// db.models.user.data[0].postIds  -- same idea here
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QLIHsAmEANsgN4CwAUMssPgFzIZhSgDmVAvlVQkZhmR5CRADzDiABSi4ADoIgAPSCHyD0WCUQB8FasnxwwcRlulyMAbQC6yALzIbVGglwhmUAK4IwuKAApcACMAKwgfAH5TAikZeQBKMmdkbkpU3n4MQQARIzggzAhRZIAVZCUVNTRCrQAaZK0MAElVJXLlCFVBUkcAawgAT0YPdmtokVES7RT6-UaWwkUAaUGFDq7kfoHcGCEYombWxVmaACViI2A3NcrBSTgoMGA4MR7LLdoQPZFDxZWBjBjZBwEADFLaZLTPQ0AC2%20ww42IvyUyVc7hY3l8AThP0RBwWSlqyCgFye1yiyHO-DJ7kS0JoyDAAAtgBgAHQ4pH2ZCcg7JVLpSigSCwRAoJoAVSwUC0SX0dGGLHYJ2QIDgMIgitYIA4aR4QvA0HgSGQTVOuCIOH2cpoCqYSp1KqeYEtWvYXH1wqNYtNklwzFl9LtI0dyWdrvt2rYKqCBCGkeVHso%20t41zAyE80tlDhAEAA7t9iKJJVn9tp-PFU%20jiRarSJubmC1pi%20bLVpy5XKGjmMhZP6wNnVfnC2Imn6A2WK-qAPTT4H4Kpwkm9uLQJ4QQQg-DIGCeEA%20K5qojAdeCXyMpkoXlVnsACUwAHlc9z-LzGCCBok7FD9YLZ-PFz8FBZFXR5gA3YFVB3PcDzcF4T3As9cAvK99hvdN7wwbAPxfN9IM-ewf2TPViLAAZZBQGRLW5AAiKiIBoqgyIo3siE8KAXlbFAHAAAwAElIejOAwHiUy7NMDCCBth1yYwCiwfxkh6TNoEYFSZX2Il6MYei6l7ftGD7Cd604FV6RodT6GSGhzIZdSuMYTCnwgfxdP2eIVQZfTmEczBsNBfwjIHdzrJSflOyoacACooucKLkAAcVwF44unGc5wwUATTzFBCBgUAIG3Gj7NrGjgTPS8VzkNcwTVDVIrnJoAHJtzzEF03PJk4AANxQJqSstJrIO3frpS4pp8CGzAAIQuCSBA6qwIgmA-BQnlrWZIxkAQEFkCCFBQBgaASXwdL2gonxCs%20I6oARBrJI5eE2XUtlDGMSwAAZrGesbawm%2078CCR6fh%206BXryT7voGiAzqUC7IG3Q7oDuyh-0B4GkVBqBwfer62SCwQGQAWiJ1VcCeE1NvTHKDAgfLc0R9NpqaoKmqJIJPHTE9kDawQEC6nUrvPZlgLYjiSBZ-sMCG5k-E8NgmUZCAYVkakUGPEUXkZciNwBoHeXZF63rgSH8f7CbCZJph1QOwg4GQS8SSoIA)

Comment: Could you pare this down to a more [mcve]?  Are you asking for implementation or type signatures or both?

Comment: Even just the type signatures for this seem pretty terrible: [look at this](https://tsplay.dev/mMyXVm).  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @jcalz yep, just wanted to get the type signatures working. mind posting it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work at all, the output types of `HasOne` and `HasMany` need to encode enough information for the `Database` class to give the right type to its `models` property.  Here is one possible example, where I just give each function's output a distinguishable interface which keeps track of the particular model:

```
const HasOne = <T extends BaseModel>(model: Model<T>): HasOne<T> => null!
interface HasOne<T> {
  type: "HasOne",
  model: T
}

const HasMany = <T extends BaseModel>(model: Model<T>): HasMany<T> => null!
interface HasMany<T> {
  type: "HasMany"
  model: T
}
```

Then the `Databaes` class should need only two generic types: `M`, corresponding to the type of the `models` constructor parameter, and `R` corresponding to the type of the `relations` constructor parameter:

```
class Database<
  M extends Record<keyof M, Model<any>>,
  R extends { [K in keyof M]?: { [P in keyof R[K]]: HasOne<any> | HasMany<any> } }
  > {
  models: Relationify<M, R>
  constructor(models: M, relations?: R) {
    this.models = models as any;
  }
}
```

I have constrained `M` to types whose property values are `Model`s of some kind, and `R` to types whose properties at the same keys of `M` must themselves have types whose property values are either the output of `HasOne` or `HasMany`.

I haven't yet defined `Relationify<M, R>`, but the goal is to take the information in both `M` and `R` and come up with a variant of `M` whose `Model`s have been augmented in the way you'd like:

```
type Relationify<M, R extends { [K in keyof M]?: any }> =
  { [K in keyof M]: M[K] extends Model<infer P> ?
    Model<P & AddProps<R[K]>> : never };
```

We map each property in `M` at key `K`, whose original type is `Model<P>` for some `P`, to a new property whose type is `Model<P & AddProps<R[K]>>`.  So the `P` part is the same.  I haven't defined `AppProps` yet, but the goal here is to take the relation from `R` corresponding to the key `K`, and turn it into the right extra model properties.

Here comes `AddProps`:

```
type AddProps<T> = (
  { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends HasOne<any> ? K : never]:
    T[K] extends HasOne<infer M> ? M : never } &
  { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends HasOne<any> ? `${Extract<K, string>}Id` : never]:
    T[K] extends HasOne<infer M> ? Extract<M, BaseModel>["id"] : never } &
  { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends HasMany<any> ? `${Extract<K, string>}s` : never]:
    T[K] extends HasMany<infer M> ? M[] : never } &
  { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends HasMany<any> ? `${Extract<K, string>}Ids` : never]:
    T[K] extends HasMany<infer M> ? Extract<M, BaseModel>["id"][] : never }
) extends infer O ? {} extends O ? unknown : { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

Oof, that's not pretty. It could probably be refactored if necessary, but the gist here is that for each property key in the relation `T`, we look at its key-value pair `K` and `T[K]`.  This is going to be something like `"userRole"`-and-`HasOne<IRoleModel>` or `"post"`-and-`HasMany<IPostModel>`.

Since we are taking the key `K` and possibly modifying it, we will need to use [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) as well as [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to do the actual modification.

Each line that starts `[K in keyof T as T[K] extends ...]` handles a different added property.  The first one checks to see if the relation is `HasOne<M>` for some model type `M`, and if so, adds a property with the same key and whose value is type `M`.  The second one also checks for `HasOne<M>`, and if it's a match, adds a property whose name has `"Id"` appended to it, and whose value is the type of the `id` property of `M`.  The last two lines do the analogous thing for `HasMany<M>`, where we are suffixing `s` and `Ids` to the keys, and returning an *array* of the model type or model id type.

Finally, since big intersections of multiple object types are not pretty, I repackage them into a single object type with the `extends infer O ? ...` clause, and if it happens that there are no added properties, I change it to `unknown` so that the above `Model<P & AddProps<R[K]>>` will become `Model<P>` instead of `Model<P & {}>`.

---

Whew!  Let's see if it works:

```
const db = new Database(
  { user: userModel, role: roleModel, post: postModel },
  {
    user:
    {
      userRole: HasOne(roleModel),
      post: HasMany(postModel)
    }
  })

/* const db: Database<{
    user: Model<IUserModel>;
    role: Model<IRoleModel>;
    post: Model<IPostModel>;
}, {
    user: {
        userRole: HasOne<IRoleModel>;
        post: HasMany<IPostModel>;
    };
}> */
```

The value `db` is known to the compiler as being a `Database<M, R>` for the appropriate `M` and `R` types.  Now we examine its `models` property:

```
db.models
/* models: Relationify<{
    user: Model<IUserModel>;
    role: Model<IRoleModel>;
    post: Model<IPostModel>;
}, {
    user: {
        userRole: HasOne<IRoleModel>;
        post: HasMany<IPostModel>;
    };
}> */
```

That's correct, but what type *is* that?  Let's examine each property in turn:

```
db.models.post // (property) post: Model<IPostModel>
db.models.role // (property) role: Model<IRoleModel>
db.models.user /* (property) user: Model<IUserModel & {
    userRole: IRoleModel;
    userRoleId: string;
    posts: IPostModel[];
    postIds: string[];
}> */
```

Looks good; the `db.models.post` and `db.models.role` types have not been touched, but `db.models.user`'s type has been augmented.  Let's just probe it a bit further:

```
db.models.user.data[0].id // string
db.models.user.data[0].name // string
db.models.user.data[0].userRole // IRoleModel
db.models.user.data[0].userRoleId // string
db.models.user.data[0].posts // IPostModel[]
db.models.user.data[0].postIds // string[]
```

That's what you expect, hooray!

---

Of course this all only deals with the type system and has very little to do with actual implementation.  Your implementation will probably drive the particulars of the `HasOne` and `HasMany` interfaces, and I fully expect that inside `DataBase`'s class body you will need to rely heavily on [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or similar in order to convince the compiler that your implementation conforms to your type signatures.  But that's outside the scope of this question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QLIHsAmEANsgN4CwAUMssPgFzIZhSgDmVAvlVQkZhmR5CRADzDiABSi4ADoIgAPSCHyD0WCUQB8FasnxwwcRlulyMAbQC6yALzIbVGglwhmUAK4IwuKAApcACMAKwgfAH5TAikZeQBKMmdkbkpU3n4MQQARIzggzAhRZOxkJRU1ZAAlcL98UQBrCABPXBghABohGLE4EGbtbQ7kqrLlCFVBUkcAaVoQZCbW9uxrKLJHSXnFlrbqyxnra0YACUwAeRAivoHkAB9kM4xsG9Eb7RSU5I+9GgBbHoYRg1fhgYBuYAwZriLpVbTJVzuFjeXwBAEiIGdZBQYhGcHudZVRK-GjIMAAC2AGAAdOjiIIHHSiIJMMgbgBuZKpdKUMDNWQoEF4iFQmHVMYVKazbZLPardY3FIfOzJaYHGW7FbHIQHWzlCaVLSiUAwaDISQfCLJGhGrYAMmQAEF8PhzPJRFVdYNkIwrgA3M2cTmUHi8-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-WDd17BLcgQQEM0Q3rVwoaIswyCeJl2UOFcgXdCIojpadf7+PEvBuEdMitWdF4QJdRpNS1bXENoD1PUiyCyNNYDvRdV3EDdU0zfdj0hpQh1gLpRb2MgcY0eohQWf4TLRNd8bxKcT5xsqHwgJ4RBEAAhAl4B1SlqMtvGHVkuGjAAdOEAARt+MZvtiPI7p9Ho5jnnmfd-NGkTJN6dCrN2BTVO0-TSX1SgqGvKzJJ8gKnNa-0AHJPzsaCwdz0o-gQTo5DuTGAUWBJlBx2ZYwJ3QFoXSveV2K-V7INg4woNw+1nAbSSNAe1AGmkmzcfR81q3c-4PtaPEG1xyHYBy-R-jZ+ntapDQnAI1QAD0ABUyDC9bjD2-khSiJHrvQAT0O3Z7f7BnHPvt2IP1vd3tbZ-3MNgxZwbh-HrcxzPCeZUnvvczdS+T7WWdByLryTRPw+aUGXAfJX5ehtbtKAhX1dMpiQpgiK0It9HY+d1l++979L9r+-pKj1DA+w3BvvaeT83bz1JInT+zMiiDz+joHucdf5b0NtCakaDtAIJLlPY+p9EbnxvtSbOyBy7l0TLIOI0A+SJD-t9QBFkqD4MBNSH2xDSH5woVAKhftVrfW-iIeElBGEYmpNHYh1d2FyEoc0RIz9-43Qyl3dqDpQHQCXowWBWhMGzyXieXaCktHZ0xLvUOxAbAGLBspPRbAzFH2QCfM+QQL7COjtSQwxhLAAAZrDUjoKwtaCkGGOIIS4txcBPHeJKmVPxC1AlOPpCIzKri8jhISao36fiNE9FicExJoSUmQNaieaJlVslMJCckrxhCwaCBIY1OhPQnCCKCWU3JFTvHZ2UsU4ajSqBAA)

Comment: Wonderfully well detailed answer, thanks!